# How to define a schema restriction that allows an enumeration value or pattern match?

Tags: regex, xsd

I am defining a `simpleType` that has a `restriction` to either be a value from an `enumeration` or a value matching a `pattern`. I realize I can do it all from the `pattern` but I want to have the picklist that the `enumeration` provides.

This is what I expected to be able to do:

```
<xs:simpleType name="both">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="one" />
    <xs:enumeration value="two" />
    <xs:pattern value="[0..9]+" />
  </xs:restriction>
<xs:simpleType>
```

But that fails since a value can't match both constraints. If I modify the pattern to allow for any enumerated value then it will fail it if only matches the pattern.

Answer (score 12):

Turns out I need a `union`. Define the enumerated type as a separate type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="enumeration">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="one" />
    <xs:enumeration value="two" />

  </xs:restriction>
<xs:simpleType>
```

Then create the target type as an enumeration:

```
<xs:simpleType name="both">
  <xs:union memberTypes="enumeration">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0..9]+" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

So now I get the pick list, or match the pattern. Exactly what I wanted!

**Update:** Can actually define both simple types as children of the `union` or via the `memberTypes` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for tip! I'd mention that it also works with both `<xs:simpleType>` elements listed within the `<xs:union>`. BTW you should mark the answer (even your own) as accepted to make clear it's the correct solution.